Question regarding sign of a trignometric quadratic functions
This question is regards of the following problem
If $\cos^2(x) + (1-c)\cos(x) + 2c - 6 \geq 0$ for every $x \in R$ than the true sets of values of $c$ is,
I tried to solve the above problem as follows for this to be true the discriminant of the above quadratic equation must be less than or equal to 0.
Doing this we get.
$$(1-c)^2 - 4(2c-6) \leq 0$$
$$c^2 - 10c + 25 \leq 0$$
However this condition is only satisfied when $c=5$ however this is not one of the options for the above question.
Could anyone point me where i am wrong, any help would be appreciated!

Is the answer $c\ge4?$

You are (implicitly) using the change of variables $u=\cos(x)$. The fact that the quadratic function on $u$ is always non-negative is not equivalent to the discriminant being $\leq 0$.
This is because the quadratic may have roots, but ones such that $|u|>1$. This would not translate into roots of the original expression since cosine only takes on values on the interval $[-1,1]$. Thus, in this case the function would be always positive or always negative.
So, we have two options:

The discriminant is $\leq 0$ $\implies$ $c= 5$.

The solutions are bigger in modulus than $1$, and the function is always positive.


But the solutions are $$\dfrac{c-1\pm \sqrt{(c-5)^2}}{2}$$
So we will have $$\left|\dfrac{c-1\pm \sqrt{(c-5)^2}}{2}\right|\geq 1\iff |c-1\pm|c-5||\geq 2\iff |c-1\pm c-5|\geq 2$$
The $-$ sign inequality leads to $|4|\geq 2$, which clearly holds. The $+$ sign inequality  is equivalent to $$|2c-6|\geq 2\iff  2c-6\geq 2  \text{ or }  2c-6\leq -2\iff  c\geq 4  \text{ or }  c\leq 2$$
Now, we need to check the function is always positive. Evaluating at $0$, we get $c-4$.
Thus, the only possibility is $c\geq 4$.

Use the method of completing the square.
Adding and subtracting $\left(\frac{1-c}{2}\right)^2$ in the given equation we get,
$$\left(\cos x+\frac{1-c}{2}\right)^2+2c-6-\left(\frac{1-c}{2}\right)^2\ge0$$
Simplify the equation to get,
$$\left(\cos x+\frac{1-c}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{c-5}{2}\right)^2\ge0$$
Now use the algebraic identity and get,
$$(\cos x-2)(\cos x-(c-3))\ge0$$
Since the first bracket is always negative, we must have $$(\cos x-(c-3))\le0$$ Or $$c\ge 3+\cos x$$
Since the given equation is true $\forall x \:\ \in \mathbb{R}$, we will take the maximum value of $\cos x$ i.e. $1$.
We then simply get, $$\boxed{c\ge4}$$
